# When does a measure have a density?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Consider a measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ and another measure $\nu$ on the same space. I'm interested in the conditions under which $\nu$ can be represented by a density function $f$ on $X$, so for measurable $S$, $\nu(S) = \int_S f \, \text{d}\mu$. A necessary condition is that for any $S$, if $\mu(S) = 0$ then $\nu(S) = 0$. Is this a sufficient condition? If not, what other conditions need to be included?

Comment: Do you know about the Radon-Nicodym theorem?

Comment: Yes to $\sigma$-finiteness, and the Radon-Nikodym theorem is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the measures are $\sigma$-finite, Radon-Nikodym's theorem applies. We can find it in any textbook about measure theory, see [Athreya's book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=9tv0taI8l6YC&printsec=frontcover&dq=measure%20theory&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=fkmZUNyUBI6RhQfd44BI&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=measure%20theory&f=false) for example.

If one of the measures is not $\sigma$-finites, the result may not hold. For example, consider $[0,1]$ with $\mu$ Lebesgue measure and $\nu$ counting measure (which is not $\sigma$-finite). Then $\mu\ll\nu$ but each singleton has measure $0$ for $\mu$ (hence if a density $f$ existed, $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, which is not possible.